# Early signs of cocaine addiction

Tags: symptoms, recreational-drugs, addiction, inhalation, substance-abuse

What are signs to look for to determine overuse or addiction to cocaine?

Comment: One might be always needing financial help when that wasn't the behaviour prior. Basically most things out of the ordinary <ie> secretive etc. Really no different than one being an alcoholic or other substance abuse.

Answer (score 3):

Some signs of addiction are enlarged pupils, increased alertness and energy, loss of interest in food and sleep, increased talkativeness, rapid mood changes, increased heart rate, nasal congestion. You can read about these and other symptoms in the articles [Cocaine Addiction Signs and Symptoms](https://luxury.rehabs.com/cocaine-addiction/symptoms-and-signs/) and [Cocaine Abuse](https://drugabuse.com/library/cocaine-abuse/).